# Creating and exporting a Metal library

Tags: ios, metal

I see that Apple documentation usually focuses on creating Metal libraries that can then [be loaded using the Metal API from Swift or Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/shader_libraries/building_a_library_with_metal_s_command-line_tools?changes=_6), but I am trying to create a library that can provide utility Metal functions to projects that would import it (so you would `#include <MyLibrary/Header.h>`. Unfortunately I can't find anywhere how to do this:

- I see no clear way of doing this as part of a Swift Package (which is what I would have preferred), since I would need a way to tell Xcode that the package contains a Metal Library it should link with the current project library
- I also tried the "Metal Library" template in Xcode, but I don't understand how it should be used.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: You can use `xcrun` to run the `metal` compiler like this `xcrun metal main.metal`. You then pass all the additional options required, like `-I` and fast math and others. As for swift packages, even though Swift 5.6 added the extensible package build system, I've tried to compile metal shaders with it and it seems like it's pretty hard to do that still, because you have to compile libraries for different platforms, so I wouldn't try that unless you are feeling like spending a lot of time on that.

Comment: @JustSomeGuy From what I understand the Metal CLI would enable me manually compiling my sources to create a library, but then what I want is to be able to link this library to a project of my choice (with its own Metal code) that would be #including the headers corresponding to my library so that it can use utility functions defined in my lib.

Comment: Oh, if you want to actually get multiple libraries to work together, you will need to use dynamic libraries. There's a WWDC talk on that